# Return values to another sheet if a cell is not empty, otherwise skip to next cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have one sheet with a list of phone extensions in which some have names associated with them and some do not. I am trying to use a function to display one the extensions with names onto another sheet, but I can't wrap my head around the correct formula.  I've tried to use the `isblank` function or the `len` function, but it doesn't seem to work the way I want. If anyone has any advice on how to make this work without using dozens of if statements, I would appreciate the help.

Here is a link to a practice sheet I am using (Edited to a public sheet): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQz4seYTcXraVkjMI2FJrLu0xRfdTEc6Fef-OESWbKwuPw_HHu4gy4Dyzk_4HvVQQbXeW5Hjbhhf5KO/pubhtml

Comment: your sheet is private

Comment: I fixed the sheet to make it public, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C, "where A is not null", 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C, "select C where A is not null", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, I have never used the query function, and I am glad to add it to my knowledge base.  This function worked perfectly for my sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:C, A1:A<>"")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!C1:C, A1:A<>"")
```

[image: 0]